# Как получить индекс массива по его ключу в JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть массив объектов:

```
var arr = [2 : {}, 5: {}];
```

Как зная `key` получить индекс?
Например для 2 индекс будет 0

Comment: А только меня смущает, что у автора в примере написана массиво-объектная конструкция, которая не существует? А массив объектов выглядит так: [ {2: "два"}, {"5": "пять"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На прямую - никак: у тебя попросту нет arr[0];
Однако, если тебе неприменно зачем-то нужно такое получить, можешь сделать пользовательскую функцию с перебором массива и возвращением номера. Что-то вроде такого

```
var arrIndex = function(key, arr){
  var i = 0; 
  for(var k in arr){if(k===key){return i;} i++;}
  return false;//если не совпало
}
var index = arrIndex(5,arr);//вернет 1 для твоего примера
```

Замечание: 5!=='5', 0!==false. Если чувствительность к типу значения ключа не  нужна (по большому счету, она, вероятно, и не особо нужна), то лучше поставить (k==key) вместо (k===key)

Comment: Спасибо! Можете уделить внимание на вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426528/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F

Comment: key для массива это и есть его индекс, поэтому хотелось бы посмотреть рабочий пример от автора этого поста :)

Comment: Jony - там тебе уже ответили про typeof - большего добавить не могу:)

 MasterAlex - об этом я уже писал, а для чего Jony оно потребовалось - то Билл Гейтс его знает)

Comment: Grinya Lesnoy, и всё таки хотелось бы посмотреть фиддл, вы написали вполне конкретный код, который в теории выдаёт ответ, вы же его проверили перед тем как написать сюда, не так ли?

Comment: Скопируй функцию arrIndex в консоль и запусти ее с var arr = []; arr[3]='a'; arr[5]='b';  arr[7]='c';  index = arrIndex('7',arr); - получишь 2 - вот тебе и будет пример; заменишь (k===key) на (k==key) - получишь тоже и с arrIndex(7,arr);

Answer (score 2):

можно через `Object.keys` , например так,

```
var arr = [ {2: "два"}, {"5": "пять"}];
console.log(arr[Object.keys(arr)[0]]);
```

запрос

```
arr[Object.keys(arr)[0]]
```

выдаст `{'2': 'два'}` а

```
arr[Object.keys(arr)[1]]
```

выдаст `{"5": "пять"}`