# Как проверить существует ли переменная?

Tags: javascript

Пробовал делать так:

```
if(par && par !== undefined){
  alert('exist');
}
```

Т-е на странице нигде не объявлена переменная `par`

Comment: http://javascript.ru/typeof и читать статью до конца

Comment: Дочитал - сказано: `par !== undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Получаешь тип и сравниваешь его с `undefined`. Если `true`, то переменная установлена.

```js
if(typeof dfshkhdkjfh !== "undefined")
  alert('Defined');
else
  alert('Not defined');
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
if(typeof par === 'undefined'){
  alert("par undefined");
}
else {
  alert("par defined");
}

var par2 = "something";

if(typeof par2 === 'undefined'){
  alert("par2 undefined");
}
else {
  alert("par2 defined");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isset(r) {
    return typeof r !== 'undefined';
}
// проверка на переменную varname в глобальном контексте
console.log(isset(window['varname']);
// проверка на переменную V у объекта
console.log(isset(App.V));
```

Удобней использовать функцию, так как часто требуется такова рода проверка.

Или более продвинутый вариант

```
function isset(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === 'undefined' || obj === null ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
```

Ну и для сверх ленивых и знающих что будет в переменной:

```
if (!!variable){
   //exist
}
```